# Commonwealth Bank of Australia said they don't have SWIFT 103 message for International money transfer

Tags: australia, international-transfer, swift

few days ago i posted [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/AusFinance/comments/7hodgn/is_it_normal_for_international_bank_transfer_to/) wondering about how long a transfer could take from Australia to Tunisia.

And today marks the 2 weeks period and i still got nothing, so i contacted my banker and he asked me that he can't do anything without something called "[SWIFT 103 message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MT103)", i told him that my mate asked his bank (commonwealth) and they said that they don't have that SWIFT thing and that all they have is [this recipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5nkd.png), so my banker told me that that recipe is a local thing that can only be acknowledge by Commonwealth bank and its clients (and maybe the Australian gouvernement ?) but for International operation that recipe doesn't mean anything to my bank and for them it's nothing more than a picture with zero credibility, and then he went out and asked another guy from another department to send him the *"SWIFT 103 Message"*  of the latest payment that i received from Australia (September 2017) and he mailed it to me, [here is it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3hD0.png), and this shows two thing :

1. The swift 103 message must exists.
2. The payment is being done through an intermediate bank (New York CitiBank).

And this is the main reason why my bank need the SWIFT message so they can confirm that the money has been really sent because we know that the money is out of my friend's account, but none of us know where is it right now, and so we need this information so we can contact that middle-man bank.

So my question to you is :

Is it within my friend's right to ask his Bank for the "Swift message" ? I am 100% sure that it exists, but the question is should CommonWealth give it to us or not ? also maybe it has a different name ? because when he was calling his bank, they told him "there is no such thing".

PS :

not sure if this can affect anything or not, but my friend is not in Australia atm, he's in Europe, but he is Australian and so is the company.

Thank you all and have a great day